# How to debug a platform signed system app using Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, adb, visual-studio-debugging

I'm currently working on a project that must be a platform signed system app to be privileged to communicate on the I2C bus of a proprietary Android device.

The manifest contains android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" and the resulting unsigned apk is signed, zipaligned and installed with this batch...

```
java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 unsigned.apk signed.apk
zipalign -f -v 4 signed.apk aligned.apk
adb install -rg aligned.apk
```

This works fine. However, I need to do extensive development running with this privilege requiring the debugger to be attached. I have tried using a custom Configuration that retains the debugger symbols while including the Mono runtime in the package only to find out that you cannot attach to an already running Android app from Xamarin.

Is there a way to create a keystore that is signed with the platform signature that I could put in ...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\ to replace debug.keystore? The idea being that the debug build-deploy process would pick this up and I'd have the privileges I need AND have attachment to the debugger.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those following, after I performed the steps from Alex, I added this to the .csproj file to get Visual Studio to use it for this specific example.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>(path)\platform.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>android</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>1</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>android</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours, thanks for your sharing again.

Comment: Done... I thought I needed to reach reputation 15 first.  I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a JKS keystore from a DER-encoded PKCS #8 private key and the corresponding PEM-encoded X.509 certificate as follows:

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform der -in platform.pk8 -nocrypt -out platform.key
openssl pkcs12 -export -in platform.x509.pem -inkey platform.key -out platform.p12
keytool -importkeystore \
    -srckeystore platform.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
    -destkeystore platform.keystore \
    -deststorepass android -destkeypass android
shred -u platform.key platform.p12
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked as expected.